# Filling an array/assoc array of immutable objects at runtime

Tags: immutability, d

Is it at all possible to fill an array or associative array of immutable objects at runtime in D?  I have a set of immutable definitions whose data is read from an external source at runtime.  Each definition also contains arrays of several other immutable objects.  However, it seems the compiler forbids instantiating immutable arrays using loops.  In this example (field data simplified):

```
immutable class Definition {
    string name;
    int size;
    immutable(Field)[string] fields;

    immutable class Field {
        int num;
        this (int num) {
            this.num = num;
        }
    }
    this(string name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        foreach (i; 0..size) {
            string key = [cast(char)('a' + i)]; // a, b, c...
            auto field = new immutable(Field)(i);
            fields[key] = field; // ERROR
        }
    }
}
class Instance {
    Definition def;
    void speak() {
        writefln("I am currently referencing definition '%s' (%d)", def.name, def.size);
    }
}

auto defA = new immutable(Definition)("AAA", 4);
auto defB = new immutable(Definition)("BBB", 6);
auto instance = new Instance();
instance.def = cast(Definition) defA;
instance.speak();
instance.def = cast(Definition) defB;
instance.speak();
```

I'm getting *Error: immutable field 'fields' initialization is not allowed in loops or after labels*.  Is there any way around this, or a better way to accomplish it?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a helper function and temporary.

```
--- test.d  2015-04-11 12:03:54.257670300 +0000
+++ test2.d 2015-04-11 12:03:59.433170300 +0000
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+import std.exception;
 import std.stdio;

 immutable class Definition {
@@ -14,11 +15,13 @@
     this(string name, int size) {
         this.name = name;
         this.size = size;
+        immutable(Field)[string] fields;
         foreach (i; 0..size) {
             string key = [cast(char)('a' + i)]; // a, b, c...
             auto field = new immutable(Field)(i);
-            fields[key] = field; // ERROR
+            add(fields, key, field);
         }
+        this.fields = fields.assumeUnique();
     }
 }
 class Instance {
@@ -38,3 +41,9 @@
    instance.def = cast(Definition) defB;
    instance.speak();
 }
+
+void add(K, V)(V[K] aa, K k, V v)
+{
+   assert(k !in aa);
+   cast()aa[k] = cast()v;
+}
```